# Why my vscode some key-words is gray color?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code, some of my code is being highlighted grey, while the rest looks as expected

The bellow picture `class` and `def` color is gray, the rest looks find though.
[image]

Comment: use the textmate scope inspector to determine the difference between the `def` words

Comment: shouldn't `'QStyleOptionGraphicItem'` be `QStyleOptionGraphicItem`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like if there’s an error in lines 14 or 15.

Syntax highlighting after an error stops working.